# Preview image not work in Jw Player 6

Tags: php, image, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I'm using the following source code to display a video file using Jw Player 6.

```
<script>
        jwplayer('video-front').setup({
          height: 540,
          width: 980,
          image: "<?php echo $base_url; ?>/sites/default/files/video-front/thumbnail-223_0002.png",
          playlist: [{
            sources: [
              { file: "<?php echo $base_url; ?>/sites/default/files/video-front/1380575675.mp4" },
              { file: "<?php echo $base_url; ?>/sites/default/files/video-front/1380575748.webm" },
              { file: "<?php echo $base_url; ?>/sites/default/files/video-front/1380575648.flv" }
            ]
          }]
        });
      </script>
```

But the image not display in my video. Only I can see a black background. What's wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
<script>
        jwplayer('video-front').setup({
          height: 540,
          width: 980,
          playlist: [{
          image: "<?php echo $base_url; ?>/sites/default/files/video-front/thumbnail-223_0002.png",
            sources: [
              { file: "<?php echo $base_url; ?>/sites/default/files/video-front/1380575675.mp4" },
              { file: "<?php echo $base_url; ?>/sites/default/files/video-front/1380575748.webm" },
              { file: "<?php echo $base_url; ?>/sites/default/files/video-front/1380575648.flv" }
            ]
          }]
        });
      </script>
```

The image needs to be inside of the playlist block. That should fix it.